# What value do tricky interview questions have?

Tags: interviewing

Original:  [puzzling.se question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80894/find-the-next-alphabet-in-the-below-series)

The OP was given the following question as part of an interview:

> Find the next letter in the sequence: H,A,H,L,U,?

My question is, What possible value could this type of question have for making a hiring decision?

I can see more obvious patterns being a screener for baseline knowledge, but I really can't see "Trick Questions"  being useful.

Comment: That's not a trick question, it's an aptitude test. It can be valuable in determining what kind of thinker you are, what your problem solving approach is, etc. A trick question is a question where the interviewer is actually trying to trick you. I see no value in trick questions. They're some persons idea of cleverness. I personally don't and won't entertain companies that traffic in the whole "trick question" interview and hiring process.

Comment: What aptitude is this testing for?

Comment: Deductive reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

It can indicate what type of person the candidate is.  If you just give up without trying, it may indicate that you aren't a problem solver and won't go deeper than the explicit instructions you have.   If you're analytical, that may benefit in some situations.

That's just a guess.  In other situations, if you try and give a wrong answer without asking for more information, that could be a red flag.   In some jobs, they may WANT an employee that won't go further than he/she is given directions for.   It really just depends on what they want in a candidate.